# What is it called when you combine textures for an object

Tags: textures, terminology

I am trying to gain a better understanding for modeling and texturing for Unreal 4 and Blender. Now my question is: What is the process/result called when packing textures into one image as shown below?

[image: Combined Texture]

Comment: In this example, is each coloured square meant to represent a different object's texture map? Or are you asking about cases where we literally texture objects with blocks of solid colour chosen from a palette texture?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Atlas-packing.

When you take several textures from one or different models and pack them into one big atlas image.

[image]
(image from http://baddabigboom.com/2010/04/texture-atlases-part-2-making-them/)

Packing is usually performed by bin-packing algorithm.

Comment: Thank you Atlas is the term I was looking for. I have models that came with Atlas images and I was unsure what they were called. So I had no idea what to search for to figure out how to get them to work in UE4 as when they are imported the textures are not applied to the models. Thanks again BIG HELP!